# Change JVM running on Tomcat7 Ubuntu 14.04 permission denied

Tags: 14.04, permissions, java, tomcat7

I am trying to change the JVM running on Tomcat7 on my Ubuntu 14.04 that is currently running on 1.7.0_121-b00. I currently have 1.8.0_121 version and I would like to use it in the Tomcat7. I have changed the configuration in /etc/default/tomcat7 as follow:

```
# Run Tomcat as this user ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use the
# default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7

# Run Tomcat as this group ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use
# the default of tomcat7.
TOMCAT7_GROUP=tomcat7

# The home directory of the Java development kit (JDK). You need at least
# JDK version 1.5. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common directories for
# OpenJDK, the Sun JDK, and various J2SE 1.5 versions are tried.
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-6-jdk
JAVA_HOME= /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

But when I restart Tomcat7 it gave me the following error

> /etc/default/tomcat7: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: Permission denied

although I already am a root in this case. Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

`CATALINA_HOME` is path where tomcat is installed.
`JAVA_HOME` is path to your jdk.
For changing the jdk to be used by tomcat you must add the below 2 lines to the `bashrc` file using editor like 'nano'

`$nano ~/.bashrc`

In the `bashrc` file append the below 2 statements:

`export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/jdk`

`export CATALINA_HOME=/path/to/your/tomcat`

Save and exit out of `.bashrc`.Changes are effective after restarting the `bashrc` file.

`$source ~/.bashrc`

Once we are done with path it’s time to run tomcat
And check by typing `http://localhost:8080`
You must see a tomcat default welcome page.

Comment: is the CATALINA_HOME will be /usr/share/tomcat7?

Comment: I don't know into which folder you have installed tomcat. I installed it in `/usr/local/tomcat`